# Potato vine is it surviving or dying?

Tags: watering, vines

Does anyone have experience with Potato vines? I recently planted some in front of my fence (front-yard).

They look like they are spreading out a bit with runners, but overall the leaves and stems look a very dark green, and not as big and bushy as I expected a couple months later. I hand watered quite a bit, not sure if this is normal.

Comment: Can you say which variety of potato vine/Solanum you planted? Or post a photo please?

Comment: Can you share some pictures please?

Comment: Where do you live?  What zone?  Most places these guys are for hanging baskets and pots just for the growing season.  These are VINES not bushes or shrubs.  Definitely need more information and PICTURES!!  Thanks!!

Comment: Hello, Jonathan!  Dying to see pictures!!

Comment: Jonathan, we are still waiting for more information and pictures.  This is a great place to learn about gardening FOR FREE.  Grins.